# Declare variable inline to use with parameter substitution

Tags: command-line, bash

I would like a reliable way of getting the name of the directory where a script lives. I would like this approach to also work when called from the same directory (most use cases involving `dirname $0` would return "." in this case). Here is one such approach:

```
FULL="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"
SHORT=${FULL##*/}
```

The logic is simple enough... move to the directory of the script, call `pwd` from there, and then strip away everything except the final directory name. However, I can't seem to figure out the syntax to convert this to a one-liner. I would like help doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use `basename` instead of your parameter substitution.

```
FULL=$(basename "$(cd $(dirname $0) ; pwd -P)")
```

The quotes are there to deal with directory names with spaces.
There must be a more elegant way to handle this, but this quick and dirty approach does what you need with a small modification to your current command.

Another method would be to rely on the `PWD` variable:

```
FULL=$(cd $(dirname $0) ; echo ${PWD##*/})
```

A method that does not require changing directory would rely on the `readlink` command:

```
FULL=$(basename "$(readlink -f $(dirname $0))")
```